# How to change proxy programmatically?

Tags: java, ruby, ubuntu, proxy, tor

I wish to test my web server which have checking to detect abusive API usage by IP address. One IP address is limited to a few hundred API calls per day.

As part of testing & simulation procedure, I need to be able to switch IP frequently & programmatically. How to do this? I am thinking of using publicly available free proxy service (or even TOR) to hide my IP. But I am not sure how to change the proxy settings programmatically.

I am using Ruby but any languages are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can make calls to the command prompt. If I were you I would make a method that uses these calls. To do this use %x command.

Edit----
This is the code I made.

```
def ipChanger(name,ip)
    return %x(netsh interface ip set address #{name} static #{ip} 255.255.255.0)
end
```

The syntax is "netsh interface ip set address "Your adapter name here" static "new ip" "new netmask" "optional default gateway"